# What does rails do if a socket closes during my request processing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets

In a ruby on rails application, if the socket to the HTTP client closes at some point during my request handler, what happens?  Does my handler run to completion (and then the response is thrown away), or is it somehow stopped or interrupted?

I'm asking rather than trying because I doubt I can solidly reproduce nicely timed socket errors at all possible points in the processing.

Answer (score 0):

with < 3.1 I think it just finishes the request, then fails.  With 3.1 I'm not so sure...because it's supposed to optionally return content chunks...